# intent pass the same values to service class

Tags: android

I have to pass intent values to service class but every time intent take the same value as it took at very first time but i need every time **different** *intent* values.

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AppointmentActivity.this,
                AlarmService.class);

        alarmIntent.putExtra("appDate", appDateString);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("appTime", appoint_time);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("appDesc", appoint_desc);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("appRemind", appoint_remind);

                sender = PendingIntent.getService(AppointmentActivity.this, 0,
                alarmIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `PendingIntent.getService` to:

```
sender = PendingIntent.getService(AppointmentActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

See if it works.

The Flag is important and `0` might not be an allowed value.